# Docker cotainers startup by python script

Tags: python, docker, automation

i need to startup my multiple docker containers by using python script but that process i have password before start the containers which that password process also add in that script. in this case i don't need create docker images to start a containers.

i need solution my problem tech people

So i add my code blow by that code i get

```
[ ERROR:root:Error setting sudo password.
Error starting cassandra container: 
Error starting fastapi container: 
Error starting vault container: ]
```

i need to start my multiple docker containers

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  I can at least say that it's usually poor form to try to invoke `sudo` within a program (it leads to password issues like what you're showing), and that using the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/) will be a little more robust than trying to use `subprocess.run(['docker', ...])`.